# How to get android device directory from Python? in Windows

Tags: android, python, windows, device

I'm making a script to sync some files from my pc to my android.

How can I list all androids directories connected (via usb) to my computer?

I tried to use this http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/488836b0-84e9-4c0c-b2cf-dd19f6e70f74 but I'm having too much trouble with all this windows dependencies. Tried to use the windll.kernel32 from ctypes too, but found it just too confusing to use (the lack of examples doesn't help).

There's any way to do this without installing an Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean detecting which removable media is Android storage, you could scan all removable drives for the Android/ or .android_secure/ folders, which would suggest the device is Android. Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/filesys.html) may be useful.

Comment: I've did that in a similar way, by checking the existence of some files, thank you anyway. I was hoping for a more 'correct' approach.

Comment: Correct as in making sure the device is Android, not a sd-reader with Android's sd in it, for example? Not sure I understand.